# Data Sync Between 3 Microservices

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, data-synchronization

[image: Microservice]

From the image given above let's say I have 2 microservices running own each DBs and the customer info is retrieved by another microservice with its own DB only for user transactions like add delete users. I am completly new to microservices and never used tools like **'Messega Brokers'** . After digging around I found data source and sink with **Kafka**. Using customser database as a source and other DBs as sink. Is this approach correct? Or how can I use **Kafka** in a proper way. Can you point me any tutorials?

**EDIT:**

I learnt that actually the tables would be all the same, I mean 3 different database but 3 same table, so logical replication would be OK . Could  using logical replication violate the microservice architecture? From the image Above I still wonder how can I use customer IDs (primary key) in Order Service API table

**EDIT 2:**

I found [this](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/) article

Answer (score 1):

We're using a microservice prototyping framework which creates database and message broker integration boilerplate code, more here: https://medium.com/@krawa76/bootstrap-node-js-microservice-stack-4a348db38e51